# Self-signed SSL certificate using AFNetworking 3.1

Tags: ios, ssl, self-signed, afnetworking-3

I'm trying to connect to a server that has self-signed SSL certificate using AFNetworking 3.1. I found several solutions but none of them works for me. I set pinning mode to none, allow invalid certificates and disable domain name validation.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration: configuration];        

AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode: AFSSLPinningModeNone];
[securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates: YES];
[securityPolicy setValidatesDomainName: NO];

[manager setSecurityPolicy: securityPolicy];
```

In my plist I set Allow Arbitrary Loads to YES in App Transport Security Settings but when I try to connect I get this error:

```
An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.
```

I can't add anything to NSExceptionDomains because the server address will be configurable from the app. Also (I don't know if that could be a problem) I'm using IP address of the server, not a domain name.

Did someone have a same problem and found solution?